# Port listening with JScript

Tags: scripting, notepad++, javascript, windows-scripting

I'm Trying to write a plugin for NotePad++ using NppScripting - a platform for writing plugins using javascript (specifically - JScript).

I was wondering if there was a way (probably via ActiveXObject) with which I could listen to a port asynchronously (specifically - I'm trying to write a CSS-X-Fire port to NPP).

I know .NET has that capability via System.Net.Sockets but I couldn't figure out a way to access it via JScript.

Any help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I eventually decided to use Adobe AIR to create my solution. It provides an amazing set of APIs, including a set of Socket APIs.

You can look at my solution [here](https://github.com/arieh/CSS-X-Fire-AIR)

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this, I would write the Socket server in .NET as a standalone EXE. 
If I understand CSS-X-Fire correctly, it is a plugin to IntelliJ Idea that listens to outgoing communications from Firebug, and then updates source files appropriately.  It sounds relatively simple. The .NET socket server could do this very easily.

Then, rather than expose a 2nd interface directly from the socket server to the scripting environment - like a COM object or a COPYDATA channel or something like that - I'd use the filesystem for communication.  In other words, script something in NPP that polls the filesystem file for updates.  When the .NET Socket server gets a message that says "Firebug just updated file X.css", the .NET Socket server can apply those updates to the filesystem file, and save changes back to the filesystem.  Because the Notepad++ app polls the filesystem, it will see the updated file and reload it, picking up those saved changes. You'd need to do cursor management within N++ intelligently.

Emacs has an "auto revert mode" for this sort of thing, so the .NET CSS-X-Fire Socket server would work with emacs out of the box - no additional scripting required. Not sure if N++ has an auto-revert equivalent.

Comment: NPP already does this poling. I guess a standalone makes more sense than a plugin. A shame I don't know how to use .NET ...